# How to elegantly shut down gorilla websocket reader?

Tags: go, websocket, goroutine, gorilla

I have a *websocket* client which spins a **goroutine**, using `Conn.ReadJSON` to read incoming JSON messages.
I would like the **goroutine** to be able to nicely react to `ctx.Done()`, hence I wrote the following code:

```
for {
        msg := new(message)
        select {
        case <- ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("Halting gracefully")
            return
        default:
            err := Conn.ReadJSON(&msg)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                break
            }
            c.inbound <- *msg
        }
    }
```

Obviously, in the current state, *ReadJSON* is a *non-blocking* function, hence it is launched and then the execution stops somewhere within (not sure where) as it waits for a message to be received.

This means that it will never *block* at the select statement and hence it will never handle `ctx.Done()` appropriately.

Gorilla documentation doesn't show any `case <- IsThereAnyNewMessage()` available.

How can it be handled elegantly?

Comment: `Obviously, in the current state, ReadJSON is a non-blocking function` no. why `**message` to `socket.ReadJSON` ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment? How would you suggest rewriting it? I believe the current best practise (seen in some other code) is to simply rely on other goroutines to close the connection (Conn in the example above) when appropriate (which shouldn't be much of an issue for the reader, since it's... just  a reader).

Comment: in this code ReadJSON is not non blocking, nothing more to understand. Closing the conn wont necessarily immediately close the reader. it is ok to deal with it like this. At some point, things will get sorted and the loop will exit.